# nth derivative of error function

Tags: differential-calculus, exponential-sums

Let $f(x)=erfi(a+x)$ and $g(x)=e^{cx}$ with
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(a+x)^2}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{\binom{m}{j}(-1)^j(a+x)^{2m-n+1}}{m!}\\
\prod_{p=1}^{n-1}(2m-2j-p+1).
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g^{(n)}(x)=c^n e^{cx}
\end{align*}
I want to find an expression for $ (f(x).g(x))^{(n)}$. I tried Leibniz rule for differentiation
\begin{align*}
&(f(x).g(x))^{(n)} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)\\
&\quad=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(a+x)^2}\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{\binom{m}{j}(-1)^j(a+x)^{2m-k+1}}{m!} \prod_{p=1}^{k-1}(2m-2j-p+1)\right)\\
&\times\left(c^{(n-k)} e^{cx}\right)
\end{align*}
I have no other way to find $ f^{(n)}$, the reason is that we need to find first derivative of error function to get rid of integral and then generalize derivative. While applying Leibniz rule $f^{(k)}=0 $ for $ k=0$. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: $f^{(0)}=f$. So, $f^{(0)}(x)=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{x+a}e^{t^2}dt$. It is not $0$.

Comment: you are right. In my summation notation $ f^{(0)}(x) \neq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{a+x}e^{t^2}~dt$. If so, then my problem will be solved

Comment: This means we can not apply Leibniz rule for error functions?

Comment: Of course, you can. Both $f$ and $g$ smooth. It might complicated.

Comment: but how? I have $n$th derivative for both $f$ and $g$. How to proceed :(

Comment: Separate the case $k=0$ in your sum.

Comment: I thought about this......Its hard to do this. How to apply Leibniz rule in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid "extended discussion", here is what I said.
\begin{align} (f(x).g(x))^{(n)} &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)\\
&=f(x)g^{(n)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x) \\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}c^ne^{cx}\int_0^{a+x}e^{t^2}dt
+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x).
\end{align}
Now use your formulas for $f^{(k)}(x)$, for $k\geq1$, and the obvious one $g^{(k)}(x)$ for any $k$.

there is a simplification of your bouble-sum. For $n\geq1$, we have
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(a+x)^2}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{\binom{m}{j}(-1)^j(a+x)^{2m-n+1}}{m!}
\prod_{p=1}^{n-1}(2m-2j-p+1) \\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(a+x)^2}(a+x)^{2m-n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{m!}\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j\binom{m}j\binom{2m-2j}{n-1}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{(a+x)^2}(a+x)^{2m-n+1}(n-1)!\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac1{m!}\binom{m}{n-m-1}\frac1{2^{n-2m-1}}.
\end{align*}
So, here is the identity I used:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j\binom{m}j\binom{2m-2j}n=\binom{m}{n-m}\frac1{2^{n-2m}}.$$
As far as proving this and similar identities goes, you may follow the procedure I outlined [in my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193611/binomial-coefficient-identity/257970#257970).

Comment: Thanks a lot.....It has solved my problem :). One last thing! can you write the formula which you used for simplification? I want to used it to simplify other expressions.